# Обстоятельства места

Tags: пунктуация

Снимок сделан в 1969 году, когда я учился на предпоследнем курсе авиационного института, имевшего военную кафедру, во время летней военной практики в военном городке в Острове (,) под Псковом, где мы приняли присягу, сдали экзамены и получили первый офицерский чин.

Нужна ли указанная запятая? Является ли это однородными обстоятельствами места? Что-то подсказывает, что нет...

Comment: Наверное, в военном городке Острове, а не в военном городке в Острове?

Comment: Остров – город, а не военный городок.

Comment: @Niemand, СПб - тоже не военный городок. Знать бы, кто эту секретную информацию купит.

Comment: Ай, какой остроумный наш дорогой @behemothus!

Comment: Всем, кто ответил, большое спасибо! Главное, что все сошлись во мнении, что запятой здесь не нужно... У автора же изначально был шедевр "в военном городке города Острова"... Пришлось немного исправить...

Comment: *в военном городке города Острова* - шедевр-то он шедевр. Но де-юре все правильно. именно так он и воспринимается это военный городок. Это крупная часть плюс сержантская учебка. Его там все знают, и что немаловажно - в Острове он один, из крупных по крайней мере. Так что как раз и получается "городок города". )))

Answer (score 4):

***Снимок сделан в 1969 году, когда я учился на предпоследнем курсе авиационного института, имевшего военную кафедру, во время летней военной практики в военном городке  Острове под Псковом, где мы приняли присягу, сдали экзамены и получили первый офицерский чин.***

Запятую лучше не ставить, так как "под Псковом" в данном случае играет роль ***несогласованного определения***, ср.: в городке (каком?) под Псковом.

Так что это не однородное обстоятельство места.

Comment: Город Остров в Псковской области - не военный городок https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Остров_(город), поэтому нельзя сказать "в военном городке Острове".

Comment: Пардон, не заметил... Да, у вас получается, что Остров - это название городка. Это не так. Думаю, что это техническая опечатка, предлог, видимо, пропал.

Answer (score 1):

**...в военном городке в г. Острове под Псковом...** По-моему, запятая здесь не нужна, поскольку это ***не однородные обстоятельства места***.

Например, **в городе Одинцово под Москвой**. Запятой здесь явно не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ изменен.**

Снимок сделан в 1969 году, когда я учился на предпоследнем курсе авиационного института, имевшего военную кафедру, **во время летней военной практики в военном городке в г. Острове под Псковом,** где мы приняли присягу, сдали экзамены и получили первый офицерский чин.

Единственное дополнение - **г. Острове,** чтобы исключить неправильное понимание статуса названия.

Answer (score 1):

Лично меня вполне устраивает ответ Екатерины. 
Но стилистика оставляет желать.

Минимальная правка (защита от Ниеманда) такая.

***Снимок сделан в 1969 году, когда я учился на предпоследнем курсе
авиационного института, имевшего военную кафедру, во время летней
военной практики в военном городке, расположенном в г. Острове под
Псковом, где мы приняли присягу, сдали экзамены и получили первый
офицерский чин***.

Но это не идеал, более кардинальным было бы убрать вовсе "военную кафедру" (а то непонятно, да, что МАИ имел такую кафедру?!) "когда я учился" и перенести "где" поближе к тому, где именно, т. е. к "городку".

***Снимок сделан на предпоследнем курсе авиационного института, в г. Острове под Псковом в 1969 году, в военном городке, где во время летней военной практики мы приняли присягу, сдали экзамены и получили первое
офицерское звание***.

(Чины в Красной армии отменили в 1917-м. А в городке том я топтал плац в 1979-м, "снимки" делать уже не разрешали).

Ну или

***Снимок сделан в г. Острове под Псковом в 1969 году, [когда я учился] на предпоследнем курсе авиационного института, в военном городке, где во время летней военной практики мы приняли присягу, сдали экзамены и получили первое
офицерское звание***.

Comment: Браво, любезный @behemothus, вы кардинально защитились от Ниеманда! "Снимок сделан (где?) в г.Острове (где именно?) на предпоследнем курсе института" – это шЫдевр! Хотя и не идеал. Главное, соответствует заголовку: кругом сплошь обстоятельства места.

Comment: Да я не защитился, я коллегу и старшего собрата от вас защитил. Вас косвенно касался только первый, минимальный, вариант правки. Остальное - не извольте беспокоиться. Можно дополнять и критиковать, но Ваши шЫдевры - на самообслуживание.